# why Android (cordova) webview reloads on relaunching the activity from other application?

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I am new to cordova programming Am loading the webview and navigating to third page (single page application) and this app goes background and am trying to bring this app foreground through other application like

```
Uri mdliveCustomUri = Uri.parse("mdlive://myhost/vsee?result=thankyou");
Intent URILaunchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mdliveCustomUri);
startActivity(URILaunchIntent);
```

But my webview is reloaded into first screen. Can anyone tell me how to avoid webview reload and i tried this solutions but am getting app crash (am using three activities)

```
  android:launchMode="singleInstance"
  android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
```

Exception Log

```
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681): Process: com.mdlive.mobile, PID: 11681
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3000, result=0, data=null} to activity    {com.mdlive.mobile/com.mdlive.mobile.MDLIVEMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3553)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3596)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at com.mdlive.mobile.MDLIVEMain.onActivityResult(MDLIVEMain.java:622)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5456)
08-01 12:11:34.694: E/AndroidRuntime(11681):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3549)
```

Comment: Strange, android:launchMode="singleInstance" in AndroidManifest.xml should solve the issu and no make the app crash

Comment: But from that activity to other activity am trying to navigate but that time the app crashes ..